# Oracle client ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle, listener

I am new on Oracle database, but I have one issue. 
On my Database server (server1) listener and database instance run correctly and I can use `sqlplus` to connect to this DB.
When I connect to database by using other server, I check the TNS configuration and it is correct but system says:

> ```
> ERROR:
> ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
> ```

My database is Oracle 10gR2

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: should be a serverfault.com / dba.stackexchange.com question

Comment: _But when I connect to database by using other server_ You mean to say that when you try to connect the same database from server?

Comment: I mean I connect to Database server by client by sqlplus or sql developer on Sqldeveloper Error "An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Vendor code 20"

Comment: So you are able to connect to database using sqlplus but not from SQL Developer?

Comment: you've verified the listener is up on the "server1" box, verified its port number, and checked the TNSNames/connection string on the other server that it matches the ip/hostname and port?

Comment: every client cannot connect to database server, but I check on firewall is disable

Comment: @aliasosx In SQL Developer when you create connection, are you using Basic or TNS as Connection Type?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: I got the same error, when I missed port number in the sqlldr

Comment: Also you can delete and re-create the listener 
Click "Start - Programs - Oracle - OraDb10g_home1 - Configuration and Migration Tools - Net Configuration Assistant"
and configure the same in tnsnames.ora file

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to set oracle to listen on all ip addresses (by default, it listens only to localhost connections.)

#### Step 1 - **Edit** `listener.ora`

This file is located in:

- Windows: `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\listener.ora`.
- Linux: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora

**Replace** `localhost` **with** `0.0.0.0`

```
# ...

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

# ...
```

#### Step 2 - Restart Oracle services

- Windows: <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

  ```
  services.msc
  ```
- Linux (CentOs):

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart oracle-xe
  ```

[image]

Comment: Finally after one day of hardship, it works!

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem. The Listener in the DB Server set to localhost. Put the hostname for the computer solve my problem.

Comment: hi, my problem is i cannot find oracleservice in service, what should i do? thank u

Comment: my admin folder doesn't have a lister.ora file, and my Services don't list "Oracle [anything]"

Comment: Also after this change, if you see ora-12514 you should replace localhost to 0.0.0.0 in tnsnames.ora

Comment: where is %ORAACLE_HOME% directory and how to get it ?

Comment: Example for Oracle 12c: `ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: How do I get here?
Windows: `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\listener.ora.`

Comment: @MichaelTolsma take mine as an example it is like: D:\app\administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora

Comment: For someone has trouble finding where `%ORACLE_HOME%` on windows: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140582/224466

Answer (score 15):

I also faced the same problem but I resolved the issue by starting the TNS listener in control panel -> administrative tools -> services ->oracle TNS listener start.I am using windows Xp and Toad to connect to Oracle.

Comment: i solve my problem by your way. my problem raise after updating OS .

Comment: **If answers here not work**, since this quesiton is closed. **here is my answer**: 1. use cmd with admin  and run `tnsping YourOracleSID`, if there is error, see the solution here, such as try `LSNRCTL.EXE start`: https://sort.veritas.com/public/documents/ccser/5.2/windowsandunix/productguides/html/ccer_install/ch03s05.htm

Answer (score 5):

Check out your TNS Names, this must not have spaces at the left side of the ALIAS

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

According to oracle online documentation

> ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

```
Cause: The connection request could not be completed because the listener is not running.

Action: Ensure that the supplied destination address matches one of the addresses used by 
the listener - compare the TNSNAMES.ORA entry with the appropriate LISTENER.ORA file (or  
TNSNAV.ORA if the connection is to go by way of an Interchange). Start the listener on 
the remote machine.
```

Comment: This is of no help to anyone who doesn't know how to perform the suggested action.