# How to provide privileges to user in oracle?

Tags: .net, windows, oracle, visual-studio

I am new to oracle. I have oracle 11g installed on my PC (windows 10).  I am trying to connect to the database and grant a privilege Create Session to a user 'ABC'. When I try to connect through cmd it keeps saying "TNS: no listener". When I go through Visual Studio, it keeps saying insufficient privileges. I, for the life of me, can't figure out what is wrong and what to do. Please help me out here.

EDIT: 
sqlplus sys/password@DBNAME as sysdba

sqlplus system/password@localhost:1521/DBNAME

Comment: Provide your connection string, command that you have used in command prompt to connect the database.

Comment: Edited my question. I think I have tried almost everything that I could understand, from Google.

Comment: Is your listener running on that port number(1521)? why happens if you just type `sqlplus / as sysdba` or `sqlplus sys/password as sysdba`?

Comment: Also your first method is wrong it should as `sqlplus sys/password@tnsname as sysdba` not DBNAME. In order to do that you should have tnsnames created to point to the remote database service,

Comment: I don't know what port number my listener is running on. What would be the tnsname? sqlplus sys/password as sysdba gives TNS: protocol adapter error and then asks for a username to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running VS as admin? If not, maybe VS doesn't have the privileges to access the `listener.ora` file in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`.
Also, you could try this:

[Oracle client ORA-12541: TNS:no listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)

Comment: I am running VS as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please check %ORACLE_HOME%\network\log\listener.log for hints as to what was wrong

you might have to re-adjust tnsnames.ora, listener.ora under %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin

Brian