# cx_oracle install error on windows

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm new to python environment. I try install cx_Oracle in windows 8.1 based on the installation guide(https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scohen/cs327e_spr15/cx_Oracle/windows.html, easy_install cx_Oracle (python package) on Windows)

When I tried to connect with cx_Oracle I have encountered an error "ORA-12170 TNS:Connection timeout occurred", "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener". Why this error happens. Does anyone help me.

I could not understand what is wrong with my question. In addition to voting my question as negative please guide what makes me wrong. I was totally helpless.

For ORA_12170 ([ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970158/ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred)) I couldn't issue an lsnrtcl status.
For ORA_12541 ([Oracle client ORA-12541: TNS:no listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)) I couldn't find (control panel -> administrative tools -> services ->oracle) oracle running.

Comment: What is the connect string you are using?

Comment: import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@ip-address/databasename')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" occurs when the server to which you are trying to connect does not have a listener running. Check that the server has a listener running and that it is responding. You can do that by issuing the command

`lsnrctl status`

on the server on which the listener is running. You can also use SQL*Plus to connect to the database using the connect string you are attempting with cx_Oracle. Once you are able to connect successfully with SQL*Plus you should have no difficulty with cx_Oracle.