# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: python, oracle, instantclient

I want to learn how to work with an Oracle Database using Python. If I understand correctly, you can use Oracle Instant Client to connect to an Oracle Database remotely, but I cannot connect. I suspect the issue is that I don't know what arguments to use for the localhost/instance combo. I believe localhost is simply my machine name, or it may be literally 'localhost' which I have tried, but I don't know how and can't find help to tell me how to locate the service name for the database instance.

In a prompt I opened python, imported cx_Oracle and used 'Easy Connect String' as specified in [this sample code](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SampleEnv.py/), using either "(my machine name)/orclpdb" or literally "localhost/orclpdb" for `DEFAULT_CONNECT_STRING`.

The sample code creates a variable `MAIN_CONNECT_STRING` which I used in a command prompt to attempt to connect to the remote database:

```
cnxn = cx_Oracle.connect(MAIN_CONNECT_STRING)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

I find answers that seem to be based on [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12541), or others referring to `tnsnames.ora`, or `listener.ora` which are files I don't have. I also tried using `instantclient-sqlplus-nt-12.2.0.1.0`.

Background:

- Windows 7
- I downloaded `cx_Oracle-6.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` and
  `instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip`
- I put the `.whl` into "C:\Python27\Scripts\"
- I used python `-m pip
  install cx_Oracle --upgrade` to install `cx_Oracle`.
- I unzipped the instant client zip and put the child folder here
  "C:\instantclient_12_2"
- I added `;C:\instantclient_12_2` to the end of `PATH`.

Comment: From the error it seems that Python and cx_Oracle are installed and running OK.  It's just the connection to the DB that needs tweaking.  What connection string do you use other tools when connecting to the DB?  Is your DB's servicename 'orclpdb'? If you have access to the DB, tools like 'lsnrctl status' will show service names.

Comment: Yes, my installation seems to be working, but I cannot connect.  How do I determine the DB service name? I think that is the problem. I have never connected to the remote DB so I can't use any of those 'xxxx status' commands.  I used the service name 'orclpdb' because that is given in the sample code I linked to in my question, since it seems like a default value that should be recognized - like the alternative given in the same sample code:  'XE'  which *I think* refers to the default service name for an installed DB, which I don't want.

Comment: You will need to ask someone who knows about the DB.  'oraclepdb' is a common default in new installations.  'XE' is used by Oracle Express Edition.

Comment: I surmised that 'orclpdb' may be the default though I couldn't find anything spelling that out...so that default service name should work because I am trying to connect to the DB Oracle provides for those of us using cx_Oracle with Instant Client, right? So the 'someone' who knows about the DB is Oracle....Unless I am misunderstanding how it is suppose to work. I want to practice actually working in an Oracle DB, loading data into it, etc. and I thought I could do that with Oracle's remote DB. Is that incorrect?

Comment: The person who knows about accessing Oracle DB is the person who installed it and either chose the default options during install, or chose custom values.  That person will also be able to help with the username and password to use, as well as the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the installation instructions found in the
cx_Oracle documentation for Windows, [cx_Oracle for Windows](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows)

Uninstall first the cx_Oracle you are using then try to follow the instructions found in the link above.

Comment: I had already used the instructions in the CX_Oracle documentation for Windows from the link you provided to do what I have done so far, and referring to the contents in that link, I believe I should be done at 3. (given 5. is done, and it is).

Comment: Maybe this one can help if the ORA-12541 is your issue [ORA-12541](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)