# Only localhost doesn't work in Oracle

Tags: oracle, localhost, tns, sqltools

I installed Oracle 11g R2 on my computer and I connected with my localhost (by SQLTools) and external hosts. Everything worked good. I turned off and turned on my computer and I can't connect to my localhost (ORA-12541). External hosts work ok still. 
I uninstalled Oracle from my computer and I installed again.
The same situation - turn off, turn on and doesn't work.
I think I have a good configuration in Oracle Net Manager like below:

[image]

and I have well-generated file listener.ora like below:

[image]

I have turned on all services too. I have well-generated sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files and paths.
I started listener by *lsnrctl start* but when I typed *lsnrctl status* I have an unknown error.

I studied many materials and already I don't have any new ideas.

Comment: What is the message you see when yiu try to connect after reboot?

Comment: I have ORA-12541 error like I typed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener

Comment: Have you checked that the listener actually started?  Run services.msc and check.

Comment: I added an answer, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problems. 
I had to set Oracle to listens on all ip addresses. My localhost didn't work despite that Oracle listens only to localhost connections default - it bluffed me. 
When I set up Oracle to listens on all ip addresses like below:

[image]

and I reloaded my services - everything is good. I had to set all services Automatic like below:

[image]

When I had my configuration as above (one address for localhost, and one for external host) and I reloaded services, everything was good too! But when I restarted computer - localhost didn't work. I checked services and when I had mine configuration - listener didn't start, I have no idea why!

[image]

Conclusion:

When I have one address (0.0.0.0) and I am reseting my computer - all services are turning on.

When I have my own configuration and I am reseting my computer - listener don't want turn on automatically (I don't know why)!

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see images (company policy) so - sorry if this won't make much sense.

If it is Windows, try to add localhost into your HOSTS file (if it isn't there). Its location is (on my Windows 7) in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`; that entry should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```