# Oracle Connection is not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, console-application

I got issue oracle connection in asp.net "ORA: 12541 TNS No lisener"

```
 OracleConnection obj=new OracleConnection(connectionstring);
 obj.open();
```

This is the above sample code.  I am trying in console application, it is working fine.

But in asp.net, it throws exception like "ORA: 12541; TNS no listener".

Both coding in same computer.

Please assist me what I am missing here...

The above code snippet is working in console, only asp.net is not able to run this snippet code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle client ORA-12541: TNS:no listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)

Comment: No Mohsin...    In console application, without ORA file, it is working fine.     Only asp.net is not able run this code.   Any specific configuration for asp.net with Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If the connection work on console application but not working on ASP.NET application also both hosted on same machine , this means that the point in IIS (web server) , after some investigation I found that this issue occur due anonymous authentication on IIS, disable it and try, also make sure that your connection string is correct.

**Follow this tutorial how to disable anonymous auth on IIS :**

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/deny-anonymous-users-access-to-a-folder.html

If you not sure if conenction string correct or not follow this for more about asp.net oracle connection strings :

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: Hi, How can i use .net framework internal server and when I use debug the code in framework?

Comment: I think you means IIS (.net web server), every windows machine have IIS just activate it https://www.laserfiche.com/support/webhelp/workflow/9.0/en-us/content/resources/Configuration/Installation%20and%20Migration/Installing%20IIS%20Components%20Windows%207%20and%20Vista.htm