# Connect as sys user using cx_Oracle in python to local database

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Trying to connect to Oracle database using Python cx_Oracle. In sqlplus I do use "sqlplus / as sysdba" as I connect to local database.
I'm trying to use the same method without password in Python, but getting ORA-01017 or ORA-12541

```
tns_entry=cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost',1521,'db1')

>>> conn = cx_Oracle.connect(mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA,dsn=tns_entry)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

>>> conn = cx_Oracle.connect("/",mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA,dsn=tns_entry)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
>>> conn = cx_Oracle.connect(mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA,dsn="TNS SERVICE")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Where am I going wrong? Please provide your input. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. My issue, I guess more on Python & cx_Oracle rather then database. Thru sqlplus I can connect using listener.

Comment: Well, you are getting Database error. It means you can reach the DB and gettin Oracle error specified as ORA-#####. I recommend to you check those error codes on Oracle Community and Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my cx_Oracle.connect is not working with connect string. So added explicit os variable

```
os.environ["ORACLE_SID"] ='db1'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("/", mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```