# Getting IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish error error while connecting to the DB

Tags: oracle, listener, tnsnames

tnsnames.ora file

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-2HN15HQU)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )


LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-2HN15HQU)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE


SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Vinay\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Vinay\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-2HN15HQU)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

[image: DB Connection]

I tried running the lsnrctl but still not able to connect to the DB. I am not able to connect to the DB session. Please advise what should I do. I have tried all the possible answer which were on stackover flow but not able to resolve the issue. Can someone help with this?

Listener control cmd prompt

Comment: Does this help? [Oracle client ORA-12541: TNS:no listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358656/oracle-client-ora-12541-tnsno-listener)

Comment: Or try to manually register the `local_listener` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459252/5841306)

Comment: What happened when you tried starting the listener (`lsnrctl start`)?

Comment: @Abra I started the services (windows->services->oracleServices) just I clicked on Start and it got started but didn't complete. Its end up with an error but now I am able to connect to the DB.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @AndrewSayer It was completed successfully. Now I am able to login into DB but got error while starting the service.

Comment: @Vicky which service? If you're able to login to the DB then the DB service must have started. If you're still having trouble, edit the current situation into your question (what isn't working, what the error message is, any config you've changed in the mean time)

Comment: @AndrewSayerThanks for the help. It's working fine now. If I face any problem and am not able to resolve by own will create a ticket here.